# Lorentz transformation of a polarized photon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

Lorentz transformations for relativistic particles can be easily understood by starting from an arbitrary reference vector $p^{\mu}_{R}=(1,0,0,1)$ (where $R$ stands for rest frame), and applying the Lorentz boosts and rotations so the final vector is $|p,\lambda\rangle=U(L(p))|p_{R},\lambda\rangle$, where $L(p)$ is the Lorentz transformation and $\lambda$ is the spin of the particle. We can understand this transformation as a product of Lorentz boosts and rotations that change from one frame to another.

However, when dealing with photons in an arbitrary polarization state, for example, $|p_R,\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{+i\phi}|p_R,+1\rangle+e^{-i\phi}|p_R,-1\rangle$, how can I find how $|p,\phi\rangle=U(L(p))|p_R,\phi\rangle$ transforms under Lorentz? I'm also confused on using $p_R$ as a photon clearly can't be at "rest".

Comment: Just think of vector potentials. By the way all photons are polarized.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you mean to replace it with the electromagnetic vector potential $A$? I haven't studied it yet but I read it transforms like $A'_x=\gamma (A_x-\frac{v}{c}V)$.

Comment: That is correct up to an extra fa tor of $1/c$. Also $V'=\gamma (V-v_x A_x) $.